# This script is always returning unknown. Even if there are files and directory inside my root folder?

Tags: python, scripting

```
for item in os.listdir("/root"):
    if os.path.isfile(item):
        print(item + "is a file")
    elif os.path.isdir(item):
        print(item + "is a dir")
    else:
        print("Unknown")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `for` loop, you are trying to check every file from the **/root** directory, not from the current one. But `os.listdir("/root)` returns only the filenames of files that are in the /root directory **without their full paths** (e.g. "my_file.txt" instead of "/root/my_file.txt"). And `os.path.isfile(...)` and `os.path.isdir(...)` require the **full paths** as their args. So, when you call `os.path.isfile(item)` or `os.path.isdir(item)` it checks whether the item exists in the **current** directory, **not the /root directory**.

Use `os.path.join(path, *paths)` to get the full paths for your items, store it in the `full_path` variable inside the loop and throw it to the `os.path.isdir(...)` and `os.path.isfile(...)` instead of the `item`. 
Here is an example:

```
for item in os.listdir("/root"):
    full_path = os.path.join("/root", item)
    if os.path.isfile(full_path):
        print(item + " is a file")
    elif os.path.isdir(full_path):
        print(item + " is a dir")
    else:
        print("Unknown")
```

Answer (score 5):

Your condition is wrong, you want to do:

```
if os.path.isfile('/root/' + item):
```